# Dropdown size setting not taking

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drop-down-menu

With the following code.....

```
ToolStripControlHost treeViewHost;
    ToolStripDropDown dropDown;
    public MyTreeViewCombo()
    {
        TreeView treeView = new TreeView();
        treeView.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        treeViewHost = new ToolStripControlHost(treeView);
        // create drop down and add it
        dropDown = new ToolStripDropDown();
        dropDown.Items.Add(treeViewHost);
    }
    public TreeView TreeView
    {
        get { return treeViewHost.Control as TreeView; }
    }
    private void ShowDropDown()
    {
        if (dropDown != null)
        {
            dropDown.Height = DropDownHeight;
            dropDown.Width = DropDownWidth;
            treeViewHost.Width = DropDownWidth;
            treeViewHost.Height = DropDownHeight;
            dropDown.Show(this, 0, this.Height);
        }
    }
    [...]
```

No matter what the dropDownHeight is set to, it will only display a small dropdown (height does not change).

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: can you take a look at the generated HTML in Firebug or something? Maybe you have a CSS rule buried somewhere?

Comment: This is .NET fat client / win forms.

Comment: Check if some other property prevents it.

Comment: AutoSize is it.  Had to set off for both TreeView and Drop down.  Thanks a ton.  Please post an answer Schaliasos and I will check green.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if some other property prevents it. Maybe the [AutoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.autosize.aspx) property is set to `true`.